# Are basic HTML Canvas drawing/animation frameworks (or at least large portions of a framework), such as processing.js still necessary?

Tags: html5-canvas, processing.js

Allow me to explain, so that this doesn't just get marked as an "opinion-based" question.

I'm learning processing.js right now, and I can't help but notice many of the similarities in functionality with what already exists in the Canvas API of Vanilla-JS. **Perhaps writing a set of large-scale animations is much more complicated in plain old Canvas than it is in processing?**

**I'm asking this because, as I continue to learn more about the vanilla APIs, I'm seeing a lot of new functionality added in JS over the years that is starting to  (VERY SLOWLY) make certain aspects of popular frameworks, no longer necessary (jQuery being a great example). I'm curious as to whether or not this is the case with Canvas and processing.js as well.**

*Personally, I'm trying to determine whether or not I should still be spending a lot of time in processing.js (I'm not asking you to make that decision for me though, but I just want some information that can help me decide what's best for me).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow allows specific non-coding questions about programming tools-like ProcessingJS, but your question seems likely to be closed as too broad.

Even so, here are my thoughts...

**Native Canvas versus ProcessingJS**

- Html5 canvas was born with a rich set of possibilities rivaling Photoshop itself. However, native canvas is a relatively low-level tool where you must handle structuring, eventing, serialization and animation with your own code.
- ProcessingJS adds structure, eventing, serialization, animation & many (amazing!) mathematical functions to native canvas. IMHO, ProcessingJS is a higher-level tool that's well worth learning.

**Extending native canvas into a higher level tool instead of a low-level tool**

- With about 500 lines of javascript, you can add a reusable framework to native canvas that adds these features in within a higher level structure: eventing (including drag/drop, scaling, rotating, hit testing, etc), serialization / deserialization.
- With about 100 more lines you can add a reusable framework to native canvas that does animation with easing.
- Even though native canvas was born with most of the capabilities needed to present even complex content, a PathObject is sorely needed in native canvas. The PathObject would serialize paths to make them reusable. With about 50 lines you can create a reusable PathObject.

**Here's a fairly useless recommendation :-p**

Try to use the right tool for the job (yeah, not specifically helpful).

- Learning native canvas alone will let you do, maybe 70% of pixel display tasks.
- Coding the extensions (above) will get you to 90%.
- Using a tool like ProcessingJS will get you to 98%.
- Yes, there are always about 2% edge cases where you either "can't get there" or must reduce your design requirements to accommodate coding limitations.

**A slightly more specific recommendation**

Since ProcessingJS merely extends native canvas, IMHO it's well worthwhile to take a few days and learn native canvas. This knowledge will let you determine the right tool for the job.